# ImportError in ipython Console in spider but not in command line ipython

Tags: opencv, anaconda, spyder

I'm working on Win64 with Anaconda 2.4.1. It was installed as described
[here](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/e27_s2015/install_opencv.html). 
From the windows command line running ipython I can import cv2. Unfortunatelly, when I try cv2.imshow() the images are not shown but only a gray region of correct size. So I tried it from spyder.
From the spyder ipython console, I cannot import cv2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-72fbbcfe2587>", line 1, in <module>
  import cv2
```

The path variable is the same, as well as the working directory. How can I get more information, which DLL is not found.
Any hints? Thanks in advance.
EDIT: cv2.waitKey() helps in the Windows command line case, my bad. But why doesn't it work in spyder?